# how to keep track of list indices when inserting new elements?

Tags: python, list, insert, indexing

I have a big list, like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', ...]
```

I would like to use a dictionary to track its indices. The dict would look like this:

```
{1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d', 5:'e', 6:'f', 7:'g', ...}
```

But then I need to be inserting new elements. And I want the indices of the list elements after the insertion point to automatically increase by 1 when inserting. Is there a quick or conventional way to do this? I usually use python, but algorithm in other forms are just fine.

UPDATE: Please dont vote down the question for no reason. I think even though some context is omitted (for simplicity), the question is fairly clear by itself. I think an answer can be provided without having to know why I needed to do this.

Comment: In C#.NET there is a Dictionary collection that does exactly what you want, I am assuming python would have something like that http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: How close does `dict(enumerate(yourlist))` get you to where you need to go?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Why do you want to "track its indices" like this?

Comment: trying to use the indices to track some other mappings to other lists... probably not the best way to do this...

Comment: I think you should ask a new question and try to explain the real problem in more detail. It's not at all clear what you mean by "track some other mappings to other lists".

Comment: It's a very, very good idea to provide some context, for two reasons: 1. It allows people to create test cases that accurately do what you want, and 2. Sometimes, the question that people ask is not the best way to do things. For example, someone might be able to suggest a better data structure or python module that you didn't know about.

Answer (score 6):

Why have a dict mapping indexes to values?  That's what the list already does:

```
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', ...]
>>> x[0]
'a'
>>> x[4]
'e'
```

If you modify the list, for example by inserting a new value, the indexes are correct automatically.

The only difference between your dict and the list itself is that the list is 0-indexed, and your dict is 1-indexed ('a' is 1).

Answer (score 0):

You state that you want to use the indices to track mappings to other lists. And this is a big dataset, so presumably lookup speed is important (dictionaries have a big advantage here).

If the index is not an absolutely essential part of the data- and only a convenient way of referring to relations- then why store things in separate lists? Have you considered a nested dictionary, so that all the related data is kept together? For example,

```
dataset = { 'a': { 'name':'Alice' , 'food':'pie' } , 'b': { 'name':'Bob' , 'food':'cake' , 'friend':'Eve' } }

>>> dataset['a']['food']
'pie'
```

This is more readable, and dictionaries offer much faster lookups for a given arbitrary piece of data vs large lists. But it's hard to recommend a tailored solution without knowing your goals. For example, it would help to know if all data can be referred to by a key (you're always looking for 'a') or whether you sometimes want to find specific values (everyone who likes pie).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class to encapsulate your integer renumbering and 1-based indexing.  See the examples at the end on how an instance of this class emulates a dict's interface, even though it is not itself a dict.

```
# define DEFAULT value that is very unlikely to be a list value
DEFAULT=object()

class IndexedList(object):
    def __init__(self, seq=None):
        self._seq = list(seq) if seq is not None else []
    def __contains__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, int):
            return 1 <= key <= len(self._seq)
        else:
            return key in self._seq
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._seq[index-1]
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self._seq[index-1] = value
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._seq)
        # or if you'd rather have it look like a dict
        # return "{%s}" % ', '.join("%d: '%s'" % (i,s) for i,s in self.iteritems())
    def iterkeys(self):
        i = 1
        while i <= len(self._seq):
            yield i
            i += 1
    def keys(self):
        return list(self.iterkeys())
    def itervalues(self):
        return iter(self._seq)
    def values(self):
        return list(self.itervalues())
    def iteritems(self):
        return enumerate(self._seq, start=1)
    def items(self):
        return list(self.iteritems())
    def insert(self, i, value):
        self._seq.insert(i-1, value)
    def pop(self, i, default=DEFAULT):
        if i in self:
            return self._seq.pop(i-1)
        else:
            if default is not DEFAULT:
                return default
            else:
                raise KeyError("%s not a valid key" % i)
    # everything else, just delegate to owned list object
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self._seq, attr)


# make an instance of IndexedList; print items just like it was a dict
il = IndexedList("abcdefg")
print il
print il.items()
# Prints
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
# [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e'), (6, 'f'), (7, 'g')]
#   or if you choose to show dict-ish output
# {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g'}
# [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e'), (6, 'f'), (7, 'g')]


# insert an item into the middle of the sequence, note that
# remaining items get incremented keys
il.insert(4,'x')
print il
print il.items()
# Prints
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
# [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'x'), (5, 'd'), (6, 'e'), (7, 'f'), (8, 'g')]


# test dict.pop
print il.pop(3)
print il
print il.items()
# Prints
# c
# ['a', 'b', 'x', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
# [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'x'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e'), (6, 'f'), (7, 'g')]


# test 'key in dict' behavior
print 0 in il
print 3 in il
print 100 in il
print il.keys()
print il.values()
# Prints
# False
# True
# False
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
# ['a', 'b', 'x', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']


# so you can treat il directly as a dict, but if you really really need a dict
# object, make one using il.iteritems
ildict = dict(il.iteritems())
print ildict
# Prints
# {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'x', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g'}
```